# Python loop to populate a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to populate an array in python more efficiently. I have a 5x3 matrix A that I am transforming into a 3x3 matrix (Z) by calculating z11, z12, ..., z33 independently. The code below works, but it's clunky and I'm hoping to automate this into a loop so that it will take an A matrix of any size (n x m) and transform it into a Z matrix of size (m x m). If someone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it!

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,0,0],
  [0,1,0],
  [0,1,1],
  [0,0,-1],
  [0,0,1]])

A1=A[:,0]
A2=A[:,1]
A3=A[:,2]

C = np.array([-2,-2, -9,-6,-4])
X = np.array([-4,-4,-8])


    z11 = (sum(A1*A1))*(C[0]/X[0])
    z12 = (sum(A1*A2))*(C[0]/X[1])
    z13 = (sum(A1*A3))*(C[0]/X[2])

    z21 = (sum(A2*A1))*(C[1]/X[0])
    z22 = (sum(A2*A2))*(C[1]/X[1])
    z23 = (sum(A2*A3))*(C[1]/X[2])

    z31 = (sum(A3*A1))*(C[2]/X[0])
    z32 = (sum(A3*A2))*(C[2]/X[1])
    z33 = (sum(A3*A3))*(C[2]/X[2])

    Z = np.array([[z11,z12,z13],
                  [z21,z22,z23],
                  [z31,z32,z33]])
```

Comment: The words `loop` and `efficient` don't go together in `numpy` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the broadcasting to achieve the same. First let's increase A by one dimension using `A[:, None]` and then multiply it with `A`. Since shape of `A[:, None]` is `(3, 1, 5)` and shape of `A` is `(3, 5)`, numpy first repeats(intuitively) the array corresponding to dimension where both array don't match and then does the multiplication. This way each column of `A` gets multiplied with every other column(to makes sure that columns are multiplied, I have used transpose) Then we can take `sum` along the last axis and multiply with `C[:, None]` to achieve the desired output.

Use:

```
m = A.shape[1]
B = A[:, None].T * A.T
Z = np.sum(B, axis = -1).astype(float)*C[:m, None]/X
```

Output:

```
>>> Z
array([[0.5  , 0.   , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 1.   , 0.25 ],
       [0.   , 2.25 , 3.375]])
```

Comment: Could you explain what is happening in the second line conceptually?

Comment: I am expanding the dimension of array A using `A[:, None]`. `A[:, None].T` has a shape of `(3, 1, 5)`, now if you multiply it with A.T of shape `(3, 5)` then numpy first does broadcasting to match the shapes of two arrays and then does the multiplication. During broadcasting numpy starts from the rightmost dimension and tries to match, since last dimension is 5 in both cases it's left as it is. Second last dimension is 1 in `A[:, None].T` and 3 in `A.T`, so this dimenstion of `A[:, None].T` is broadcasted to 3..so on.

Comment: So Simply, this way we are able to repeat the array and then multiply it with A, so each column is multiplied with every other column. See the broadcasting for second last dimension of `A[:, None].T`, each (1, 5) array of `A[:, None].T` is column of A, and when `A[:, None].T` gets broadcast from `(3, 1, 5)` to `(3, 3, 5)`, each column is being repeated 3 times.

Comment: Read here: [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! I really appreciate the help

Comment: You are welocme.